# ERROR:Type: ArgumentCountError, Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sucede que estoy mostrando algunos datos desde mi Base de Datos por medio de algunos Foreach, en los cuales estoy utilizando echo para mostrar el valor de cada campo que requiero. Hasta ahora he utilizado en mi consulta sql, en la condición del WHERE cualquier valor que me arroje un resultado para mostrarlo, sin embargo esto debo de hacerlo por medio de alguna variable, en este caso seria $rut_usu, que almacenará el rut seleccionado desde un select(listboxt) en la vista. Pero al agregar en el modelo, en la consulta sql mi variable(que aun no tiene ningún valor, porque no he seleccionado ningún valor del listboxt) me arroja el siguiente error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function M_Calendar::monday(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\C_Calendar.php on line 23 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\models\M_Calendar.php

Line Number: 106

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\C_Calendar.php
Line: 23
Function: monday

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

¿Cual sería la solución para esto ?¿Debería de hacer lo que requiero de alguna otra forma?

Les dejo mi código:

Controlador:

```
public function index(){


        $this->load->view('layouts/Header.php');
        $this->load->view('layouts/Menu.php');
        $this->load->model('M_Calendar');
        $data['monday'] = $this->M_Calendar->monday();
        $data['tuesday'] = $this->M_Calendar->tuesday(); 
        $data['Wednesday'] = $this->M_Calendar->wednesday();
        $data['thursday'] = $this->M_Calendar->thursday();
        $data['friday'] = $this->M_Calendar->friday();  
        $data['saturday'] = $this->M_Calendar->saturday();
        $data['usuarios'] = $this->M_Calendar->get_usuarios();

        $this->load->view('usuarios/V_Consulta_Horarios.php',$data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/Footer.php');




}
```

Modelo (Tengo varias funciones como esta, desde el lunes al sabado)

```
public function  monday($rut_usu){


$this->db->select('MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS hrs_ini, MAX(horario.hrs_ter) AS hrs_ter ');
$this->db->from('horario');
$this->db->join('usuarios','horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu');
$this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu',$rut_usu); 
$this->db->where('horario.lunes','ATTE. ESTUDIANTES');
$this->db->where('fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario)');
$this->db->limit('14');
$monday = $this->db->get();


  if($monday->num_rows() > 0 ){

    return $monday->result();

    }

}
```

Las variables las estoy mostrando dentro de  un javascript usando fullcalendar, que como mencione antes funcionaba bien

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instea
{
    dow: [ 1], // Monday

    <?php foreach($monday as $row){?>
       start: '<?php  $inicio= "00:00"; $start1_ok = $row->hrs_ini;

    if (empty($start1_ok)) { echo $inicio;}

    else { echo $start1_ok;} ?>',  // empty evalúa si el campo se encuentra vació o si es cero
    end: '<?php echo $row->hrs_ter ;?>' 
    <?php }?>

},
```

Answer (score 1):

El error que estas recibiendo es por que no estas enviando todos los parametros requeridos en el where.

Tu ultimo where esta asi:

```
$this->db->where('fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario)');
```

Por lo que te falta el segundo parámetro necesario en el where.

El primer parametro es la columna que vas a comparar, y el segundo el valor con el que comparas.

TU where deberia quedar de la forma:

```
$this->db->where('fecha_registro', '(SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario)');
```

Adicional a esto la funcion monday necesita un parametro

```
public function  monday($rut_usu)
```

Para probar que estas obteniendo datos en tu consulta, envia un parametro $rut_usu que se encuentre en tu base de datos, algo asi:

```
$data['monday'] = $this->M_Calendar->monday("1234567");
```

Comment: Si reconoce esa parte del where, lo copie tal cual mencionaste y  me aparece el mismo error, por lo que asumo que me aparece por la variable que se encuentra vacia en el where, en  $this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu',$rut_usu);

Comment: @CristianOx21 Acabo de editar la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora no me arroja el error, sin embargo tampoco me muestra los echo, pero, si agrego el mismo valor en el where,  aquí $this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu= "17811942-4" '); En vez de la variable $rut_usu, se muestra correctamente. No se que podría ser  :c